# unresponsive javascript, on clicking submit

Tags: javascript, html

the below is a part of code in my project. I want the java script to display another php page after submitting the form to the database. for testing purpose i tried a simple alert box to be displayed on click of submit button of form. but the script shows no response`

```
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0">
    <tr> 
        <td height="31">
            <form onsubmit="open()" action="addguestbook.php" method="post">
                <font face="Verdana" size="2" >
                    Name:
                </font>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td>
            <font face="Verdana"size="2">E-mail:</font>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="email">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td height="31">
            <font face="Verdana" size="2">Comment:</font>
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea rows="4" name="comment" cols="23" wrap="hard"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td height="31">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="Reset"     value="Reset">
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<strong>
    <a href="viewguestbook.php">View Guestbook</a>
</strong>

<script>
function open() {
    alert("Welcome");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ive located the script just after the end of form and also before end of body. but both show no response

Comment: First of all, fix your wrong HTML code – you can not place the form element where you did. It either has to be completely located within one table cell, or around the complete table.

Comment: Well the form works fine. It updates data to database as it should.

Comment: The problem is when i add js

Comment: Try renaming your function. There's already `window.open()`, redefining it might be prevented.

Comment: Yems your right thanks. The over writing was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some points:

- `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` and other tabular elements must be used only for tabular data. That's not your case. Consider using CSS tables instead.
- `<font>` elements was deprecated in 4.01. Use CSS instead.
- Avoid inline JS event listeners, add them using JS instead of HTML.
- Avoid global functions, which can conflict with native ones: [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open).

Try this:

```html
<form id="addGuest" action="addguestbook.php" method="post">
    <label class="row">
        <span>Name:</span>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
    </label>
    <label class="row">
        <span>E-mail:</span>
        <input type="text" name="email" />
    </label>
    <label class="row">
        <span>Comment:</span>
        <textarea rows="4" name="comment" cols="23" wrap="hard"></textarea>
    </label>
    <span class="row push">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="Reset" value="Reset" />
    </span>
</form>
```

```css
#addGuest {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#addGuest > .row {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: .8em;
    display: table-row;
}
#addGuest > .row > span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#addGuest > .row.push:before {
    content: '';
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```js
document.getElementById('addGuest').onsubmit = function() {
    alert("Welcome");
};
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zdV9f/)